# Robust regression with Sandwich estimator

Tags: r, robust, lm, sandwich, rlm

I understand that `rlm` (robust regression) addresses issues of outliers and influential observations, but does not address heteroskedasticity. I have come to learn that heterogenity of variance can be addressed by using functions in the sandwich package. Can one use both `rlm` and `sandwich` estimation?

Comment: `lmrob()` within the robustbase package uses a sandwich type estimator.

Comment: Thank you! What are some tips for choosing among `rlm`, `lmrob` and `lstReg` packages?

Comment: I cannot remember enough about `rlm()` and `lmrob()` to choose between them. I know nothing about lstReg.